# Error when running `sudo apt-get update`

Tags: release-juno, updates, apt, ppa

I've got the following error(s):

```
Hit:1 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                         
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                   
Hit:5 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                  
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Hit:7 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease                                                                      
Hit:8 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                        
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                         
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease                                                            
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/docky/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried accessing the link that had the error, and it is true, there is no "bionic" dist folder. Any fix for this?

EDIT: I have fixed it by running `sudo add-apt-repository --remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by running `sudo add-apt-repository --remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu`.